# Exception thrown when handling an exception (Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException:

Tags: symfony

Why does adding an indent in the **routing.yml** file give an error?

```
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////

```
(7/7) Twig_Error_Runtime
    An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template 
("The file "C:\OSPanel\domains\symfony/app/config\routing.yml" 
does not contain valid YAML in 
C:\OSPanel\domains\symfony/app/config\routing.yml 
(which is being imported from 
"C:\OSPanel\domains\symfony/app/config/routing_dev.yml").").
```

Answer (score 0):

YAML has a strict [syntax](https://yaml.org/start.html) and any little mistake will cause an error. The error text is absolutely clear `does not contain valid YAML`. Tab indent is not allowed.